# Pulling Data with Column Names from a Different Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm pulling data from a table with ambiguous column names (table 1).  There's another table that has a dictionary of what the ambiguous column names mean (table 2).  There are enough columns in the data set where I don't want to type this out 'SELECT a AS a_name, b AS b_name...'.  I would like to get all the data from table 1 but rename the columns according to table 2.

Example Table 1:

```
id  A1   A2   A3  B1 B2 B3
1  foo1 foo2 foo3 1  1  0
2  bar1 bar2 bar3 2  3  4
...
```

Example Table 2:

```
column_ref   col_definition
        A1           apples
        A2        aardvarks
        A3         androids
        B1            bears
        B2            beers
        B3            boats
```

Example output:

```
id apples aardvarks   androids  bears beers boats
1    foo1      foo2       foo3      1     1     0
2    bar1      bar2       bar3      2     3     4
...
```

This SO question comes close:
[Retrieve column names from a different table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518012/retrieve-column-names-from-a-different-table)

Except that I would have to type/copy this about 200 times for every column.

Is there a way I can join them to get the names? Or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost does what you want except it doesn't preserve data type. I used nvarchar.

```
/* Create new table for data with new column headers */
create table Table_3
(
/* Temp column, will delete later */
T3 varchar
)

/* Select column definitions into temp table */
select * 
into #TempTable
from
(
    select a.col_definition from Table_2 a
    join 
    (
        /* Get column names for Table_1 to join on */
        select column_name from SANDBOX.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        Where TABLE_NAME = N'Table_1'
    ) b
    on a.column_ref=b.column_name
) T

declare @ColDf nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

/* Loop through column definitions in #TempTable */
while exists (select * from #TempTable)
begin

        select @ColDf = (select top 1 ColDf
                        from #TempTable
                        order by ColDf asc)

        /* Add column using each column definition as column name */
        set @sql = 'alter table Table_3 add ' + @ColDf + ' nvarchar(max)'
        exec (@sql)

        delete #TempTable
        where ColDf = @ColDf

end

/* Remove temp table */ 
drop table #TempTable

/* Remove temp column */
alter table Table_3
drop column T3

/* Copy data from Table_1 into Table_3 */
insert into Table_3
select * from Table_1

/* View results */
select * from Table_3
```

Comment: This is great!  I think I'll do this in the future.  What I ended up doing was exporting both tables and using python to change the table.  Thanks!